# Validation rule to disqualify leads before conversion (based on certain criteria)

Tags: validation-rule, lead-conversion

Is it possible to implement a data validation rule to disqualify leads which annual revenue is less than £50,000K?

How to apply this limitation at the time of conversion into a contact/account/opportunity?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that disqualification means you have to restrict the lead from the conversion process. You can use the 'IsConverted' field on the lead object along with the annual revenue field.

Example : `AND(IsConverted, AnnualRevenue__c < 50000)`.

This will restrict the lead with revenue of less than 50000 from conversion.